# Drop in the ocean

Tags: athletic-performance

the training of the average gym bro is just a drop in the ocean, each muscle gets at most 7 hours of stimulus out of  168 weekly hours, when considering the most DEDICATED and EXTREME people.

if it is true that nature selects animals based on what they adapt, like humans developed hip problems to become better at sitting the same way we developed pregnancy problems to evolve to walking or lost our prenhensile feet to be better at running.

some people adapt to sleeping only a few minutes a day but on multiple sessions because that's what they always did.

so, since the average Bro is basically a normal human with 4.17% difference, it has slightly more muscle than the average guy.

is there a safe and healthy method to even the ratio? I don't wanna be a 4.17% athlete.

assuming my sleeping schedule of 9 hours a day, What Jobs can I get to gain anotber 20 to 30 weekly hours of adaptation to training?

the question in short is: What job puts the body throughout more physical stress which results in adaptations that are benifical to athelticism such as moving thyself through space with power and speed?

the job would not substitute Training sessions and preferably would be at really high intensity.

or if not, what other way is there to transform the drop in the ocean that is training into a small sea??

Comment: now some may say that adaptations happen over ages.... which is a basic misconception of evolution, Natural selection can take million of years, adaptations can happen in one generation or one lifetime.

Comment: Your question seems to be more theoretical in nature.. While jobs like free diver or farmer, or you climb mountains in tribal villages in brazil, might put your body at stress and allow it to adapt, it will only adapt itself to doing its job.. so a free diver will be skinny and be able to hold breath and have muscles for swimming.. But if the answer was known, we would be doing these things for every athlete in Olympics, no? Arnold trained 2-3 hours a day not including cardio so 12-18 hours plus few hours of cardio.. and that was on steroids, your body is not naturally capable of doing this.

Comment: 20-30 hours of training is a bit much on the body, and 20-30 hours of physical labor in a job would either slowly and inefficiently build your body for that job(lets say free diver where you dive all day for food, or ride you bike all day to deliver mail), or it would cause you to lose muscle mass since your body would be weak after so many hours. There is a theory that simplicity in life plus physical stress such as 40 hours of pure work a week+, can extend your life, but it wont evolve you

Comment: What is your current training, and what is your goal? Athletics are not wholly fungible.

Comment: Going by my research binges into routines, I submit you might be mistaken in your assumption that recovery time is “not training.” Training / exertion time isn’t what builds muscle; it breaks down muscle and tells the body to build more in its place afterwards